# Export file from iOS app in swift

Tags: ios, file, csv, swift, export

I'm fairly new to Swift and iOS development in general. My app has a model that can easily be expressed as comma separated values (csv), so naturally I want the user to be able to export the data as an csv file and opening that file in another application. Since I didn't find any examples in Swift, I gave it a try on my own:

```
func ExportToCSV(delegate: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate){
    let fileName = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("myFile.csv")
    let url: NSURL! = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileName)

    var data  = "Date,Time,Count\n2014-11-21,14.00,42"

    data.writeToURL(url, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    if url != nil {
        let docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: url)
        docController.UTI = "public.comma-separated-values-text"
        docController.delegate = delegate
        docController.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

(the delegate parameter is the view that calls the function, as in `MyClass.ExportToCSV(self)`)

This works, mostly, and I see the following views:

[image]
[image]

However, in the Simulator I get the following warning:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <QLRemotePreviewContentController: 0x7fcd720da800>.
```

as well as

```
Unknown activity items supplied: ("<QLPrintPageRenderer: 0x7fcd73861ee0>","<UIPrintInfo: 0x7fcd714b9030>")
```

when I click the *action* button, then after a while

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x10e032b10> { 
    count = 1, contents = "XPCErrorDescription" 
    => <string: 0x10e032f18> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

and when I click *Mail* there is a crash with the following error:

```
viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain 
    Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" 
    UserInfo=0x7fcd71631460 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
<MFMailComposeRemoteViewController: 0x7fcd73864aa0> timed out waiting for fence 
    barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService
```

Although on the actual device everything works as planned, so many errors throw me off a bit. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem at the moment. Did you find a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @JannikArndt i am testing with your function but i get the message `UIDocumentInteractionController delegate must implement documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: to allow preview` i am new to swift 2, how do i implement from a delegate?

Comment: @JannikArndt did you manage to export/email your csv file?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to objects already have been deallocated when they are accessed by the mail or printing app. Try to declare your `docController` and `url` variables as class properties so they keep alive as long as the view controller exists.

Comment: Unfortunately that results in the exact same errors. And also: Do I really have to care about allocation in Swift?